# Building WCF Service using unmanaged C/C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, .net, wcf

I want to leverage the performance benefits of unmanaged C/C++ libraries I already code and tested, in building a WCF service. But I have not found any information how best to go about this please. 
I have an application written in C/C++ but I would like to make it available as a service, and since I am familiar with WCF, I want to know what ways, if any I can go about doing this without loosing out on what WCF offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is a managed library, but you can look at the Windows Web Services API (WWSAPI), a native code library which contains a subset of what WCF offers. You can find more information about this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435(v=vs.85).aspx or http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wwsapi.